# IE not persisting cookie in multiple subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, internet-explorer-11

A very wired issue I'm facing in IE 11 related to cookies storage.
I have a project with multiple subdomain like this  https://abc.def.ghi.jkl.com

Whenever I'm landing to my this website my cookies are present in browser but the moment I'm going to some other page of same website. the cookies are getting disappeared from browser.
Same issue I tested in Chrome and Firefox as well, the cookies are getting stored and persistent through out the project no matter i move to N no. of pages.
I assume there is something specially related to IE 11 only because I checked in edge and its working there also.
I'm storing cookies from PHP 5.4 using setcookie();

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether you had applied any security to the root domain? If yes, for testing purposes try to disable it and see whether it fix the issue for the IE 11 browser. Also let us know whether you had set any path while setting cookie or using wildcards in it. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: This is the way i'm saving cookie

setcookie("mycookie", "123", 0, '/');

Is domian required to persist cookie in multiple subdomains ?

Comment: I try to refer to this [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). If we check the **domain** parameter, The (sub)domain that the cookie is available to. Setting this to a subdomain (such as 'www.example.com') will make the cookie available to that subdomain and all other sub-domains of it (i.e. w2.www.example.com). To make the cookie available to the whole domain (including all subdomains of it), simply set the value to the domain name ('example.com', in this case). So you can add a domain parameter and let us know about the test results.